# NGINX Remote Editing of Configurations

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm currently running a number of servers, each running NGINX used as reverse proxies to other websites. However, if I need to change a backend IP address or change other variables within NGINX, I need to manually SSH into the server and change the configurations OR log onto NGINX Proxy Manager.
What I'm looking to do is create a central website that will enable me to edit NGINX variables such as 'proxy_pass' and send the updated value to the selected remote server, updating the NGINX config and reloading the service.

Is there any current way to do this and how could I implement that? What comes to mind is some kind of CURL request to the remote server, and then I'm not sure how I'd automatically rewrite the correct portion of NGINX config etc.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you have root access on those servers, all you need is a service or a script that will fill the new values. The simplest way I see fit is to do it with a bash script and a template for the config file.

Template config file: `/home/user/nginx_config/nginx.config.sample`:

```
-- your generic config settings
proxy_pass
location /your/location {
    proxy_pass {{proxy_pass}};
}
-- rest of standard file
```

The bash script for filling the template: `/home/user/nginx_config/generator.sh`

```sh
new_ip=$1
template_path="/home/user/nginx_config/nginx.config.sample"
config_path="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

if [[ -z $1 ]]
then echo "Missing IP param"; exit;
fi

cp "$config_path" "${config_path}.bak"
sed "s/{{proxy_pass}}/$new_ip/g" "$template_path" > "$config_path"
echo "Done! Updated $config_path file to $1:"
cat "$config_path"
```

Then, all you need to do is to make a local script to connect using ssh and run the generator script (with `1.2.3.4` as your new IP address)

```
sshpass -p password ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oCheckHostIP=no user@your_server "bash /home/user/nginx_config/generator.sh 1.2.3.4"
```